# How to play pre/post-roll ads on facebook using jwplayer?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, meta-tags, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I have successfully posted videos on `facebook` using `jwplayer` and make it playable on facebook like youtube.

Here is my code-

```
<meta property="og:type" content="movie" /> 
<meta property="og:video:height" content="260" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width" content="420" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />  
<meta property="og:title" name="title" content="Drunk Guy Runs Over Flower Girl"/>
<meta property="og:description" name="description" content="This is a fail! Mayb he's!"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="Drunk, Guy, Runs, Over, Flower, Girl, "/>
<meta property='og:image' content="http://site.com/video_upload/video_imgs/big_1467487783.jpg" />
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://player.longtailvideo.com   /player.swf?file=http://site.com/video_upload/big_1467487783.mp4&image=http://site.com/images/logo.png&autostart=true&advertising: {client:'vast',schedule: { myPreroll: { offset: 'pre',tag: 'http://xp122.zedo.com/jsc/c2/fns.vast?n=2135__amp__c=109/1__amp__d=22__amp__s=1__amp__v=vast2__amp__pu=__page-url____amp__ru=__referrer____amp__pw=__player-width____amp__ph=__player-height____amp__z=__random-number__'}}}" />
<meta property="og:video" content="http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf?file=http://site.com/video_upload/big_1467487783.mp4&image=http://site.com/images/logo.png&autostart=true&advertising: {client:'vast',schedule: { myPreroll: { offset: 'pre',tag: 'http://xp122.zedo.com/jsc/c2/fns.vast?n=2135__amp__c=109/1__amp__d=22__amp__s=1__amp__v=vast2__amp__pu=__page-url____amp__ru=__referrer____amp__pw=__player-width____amp__ph=__player-height____amp__z=__random-number__'}}}" />
```

**My issue is:**
How to send pre/post roll ads on facebook so that it can play on facebook as it plays in my website which most probably needs to send through "og:video" tag

[Related Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827139/does-facebook-allow-for-calls-out-to-an-ad-server-when-sharing-a-video-with-open)

Comment: I'm afraid ads get stripped from Facebook embeds.

Comment: @EthanLongTail  Sir, Does jwplayer support ads on fb? yes or no? if yes, how?

Comment: It does not. We do not support ads on fb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Longtail, ads get stripped from Facebook embeds.Facebook do not support ads from Longtail.whereas You need to create a facebook app and pass ad tags like Youtube ads are working.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you need to use `config` tag instead of `?file=`

Like this:

`http://player.longtailvideo.com/player.swf?config=`

And add your video and ads tag in config file.